# Guides or tutorials for propane automated RIMS / HERMS

Tags: propane-burner, rims

I'm considering trying to piece together a propane HERMS system, inspired by the awesome-looking [Blichmann Tower of Power](http://www.blichmannengineering.com/TOWER_of_POWER/TOWER_of_POWER.html). I know there are several well-known electric HERMS guides (e.g. [The Electric Brewery](http://www.theelectricbrewery.com) and [Brutus](http://www.alenuts.com/Alenuts/brutus.html)), but I want to stick with propane for now.

Are there any good build guides? Where should I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Brutus build is not electric, but natural gas, so that may in fact be a good place to start, especially for seeing how the flame control works (temp controller + pilot and valve.) The write-ups are very good and many have successfully built clones. A new spring is needed on the honeywell valves to convert from natural gas to propane - [this blog](http://homebrewacademy.com/brutus-10-gas-system) describes the process.

There are a couple of others pages with propane builds:

[2-vessel gas fired HERMS build](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f51/2-vessel-gas-fired-herms-build-310657/)

This one is nice and simple - just one pump and doesn't require any kind of pilot or valve on the propane burner since the mash is done in a cooler.
[image]

[Single tier HERMS build](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f51/single-tier-herms-build-293204/)

This is a single tier system, like the Brutus/Electric Brewery, using PIDs and a honeywell valve to control the flame.

[image: Single tier system]

Comment: Nice post and pics.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional forums are a good place to start.  Often people share pics and advice on how they built theirs.

Comment: just so you know, that wasn't my downvote. Perhaps including a link to the forums you have in mind would have been a help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but its OK.  This format is about up votes and down votes.  You gotta take it like a man (or a woman if that's your sitch).